# Form submission with action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" causing logout

Tags: php, html

Keep in mind beginner mode on here.
I am making an e-commerce site that searches products from a database.
The login I use is based on 0s and 1s in database.
When logged in as admin and using search feature on admin.php page i get logged out or redirected to frontPage. The same search feature works properly on the frontPage.

This is the part where i submit form on admin.php.

```
<div id="mainArea">
    <form id="searchBox" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"><input id="search" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Search Products" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" style="width:75px;height:36px"/></form>
</div>
    <div id="show">
        <?php
            include("searchAdmin.php");
        ?> 
    </div>
```

Top of the admin.php page looks like this :

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['myusername'];
?>
```

Search is this in adminSearch.php:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']){
include ("connection.php");

$title = (trim($_POST['title'])=="")?
die ("You did not enter any search criteria"):
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);

$query = "select * from beer where upper(beer_name) like '%".strtoupper($title) ."%' OR upper(beer_descr) like '%". strtoupper($title) ."%' OR upper(beer_categ) like '%". strtoupper($title) ."%'";

if(! ($result = mysql_query($query)))
die ("No matches found. Please search again.</body></html>");
echo "<table border=1>";
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td rowspan=3>" . '<img src="images/'. $rows['beer_image'] . '.jpg"/>'."</td><td>".$rows['beer_name']."</td><td><a href='updateBeer.php?id=". $rows['beer_id'] ."'>Update</a></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$rows['beer_categ']."</td><td><a href='deleteBeer.php?id=". $rows['beer_id'] ."'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$rows['beer_descr']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['beer_cost']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else include("showAdmin.php");
?>
```

Edit: Forgot to show the end of my login php looks like this.
It sends me to admin page properly but when i do the search on the admin page it logs me out or sends me to frontPage.

```
    if($count==1){
        if($auth==1){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
            $_SESSION['auth']=$auth;
            header("location: /admin.php");
            }
        elseif($auth==0){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
            $_SESSION['auth']=$auth;
            header("location: /user.php");
        }
    }
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

My logout looks like this on same admin page:

```
<div id="login1">
<font color="white">Logged in with Administrator privilages as: <?php echo $name ?>.</font><br /><form id="logout" method="post" name="logout" action="logout.php"><input name="logout" type="submit" value="Logout" style="width:75px;height:22px"><br />
</div>
```

And the logout.php reads:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['logout'])){
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: /frontPage.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: first change if ($_POST['submit']){ to if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){, this is PHP not C :-)

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). And you're not declaring the result of `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])` to a variable. Moreover, you need to escape `%` and `_` in LIKE queries, use [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/addcslashes) for that. And you need to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting database records to your HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, you are using a variable $result which may be part of your problem.

From what i have seen, you don't declare or assign a value to $result so the comparison in the if statement is probably not doing what you intended.

My suggestion is to simplify your code by removing the if statement, for debugging purposes, and see if you get the same issue.

Also add some alert boxes to debug your code so you can identify which part of your code is redirecting you to the log out code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried your suggestions but no luck. Also, I can't see or understand how it would be redirected to the logout but I edited it in if you can bother taking another look. Is it possible its creating a new session when it reloads?

Comment: I used alert boxes and figured out I hadn't closed logout form that was causing the error. Thank you for the handy tip.

Answer (score 0):

In Place of

```
<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

use

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

I think this simple mistake is causing the error. Hope luck will be with you this time.